# Swift More Information Create User

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello i want that when a User creates a Account he have to also write his Full Name, Phone Number into the registration... but i only got this code...
How can i Integrate the Full name and Phonenumber into the registration
Thanks for your help

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPhoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmuserPasswordTextField: UITextField!


    private var authUser : User? {
        return Auth.auth().currentUser
    }

    public func sendVerificationMail() {
        if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {
            self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                // Notify the user that the mail has sent or couldn't because of an error.
            })
        }
        else {
            // Either the user is not available, or the user is already verified.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Sign up button tapped")


        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil {
              print("User has Signed Up")


                self.sendVerificationMail()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVerify", sender: nil)

            }
            if error != nil {
                print("User cant Sign Up")
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the user's display name (and if needed photo URL) in a separate call to Firebase Authentication. From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

> ```
> let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
> changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
> changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
>   // ...
> }
> ```

As far as I can determine, the [phone number in a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo#phonenumber) is only kept if you use [phone number verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone). There is no way to set it yourself outside of that.

If you want to just store the number, consider using another storage mechanism, such as the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore. See some of the previous [questions on storing additional user data](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+swift+firebase+store+user+data).